# Effect of sample size in t test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does t statistic increase with the sample size?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/why-does-t-statistic-increase-with-the-sample-size)

In t test,the test statistic is
$$
    t = \frac{\overline{x} - \mu_0}{s/\sqrt{n}} 
$$

I wonder what effect of the sample size $n$ has on the t test?

For example, as $n$ increases, I thought $t$ will increases at first, but later I realized $s$ is at the scale of $1/\sqrt{n-1}$. So $s/\sqrt{n}$ seems not to decrease as $n$ increase?

What other effect does $n$ have?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related: [Why does t statistic increase with the sample size?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13676/1909).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the t distribution has heavier tails than the normal distribution the comparable critical value will be larger in absolute value than for the standard normal distribution.  But the distribution will converge to the normal as the degrees of freedom (n-1 in your example) increase. Keep in mind that s is a random variable and it changes with the sample size.  I think this is a complete answer to your question.  But the question is very basic and there must be numerous questions on this site where at least in combination all parts of your question are answered.

Answer (score 0):

If data is Normal($\mu$,$\sigma^2$), the distribution of the the $t$ statistic is the same for every $n$ (namely, it follows a $t$ distribution). What changes is the number of degrees of freedom. See [this plot](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Student_t_pdf.svg/325px-Student_t_pdf.svg.png&imgrefurl=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution&h=260&w=325&sz=30&tbnid=lCiU_quPgdIriM%3a&tbnh=90&tbnw=113&zoom=1&usg=__PZ_qFSjvhMpWQoDfq13-8S3YHxQ=&docid=wAdMhj1iIhWS9M&sa=X&ei=JSZ3UPimMM2I0QHXhICgAw&ved=0CDcQ9QEwAg&dur=169) to see how it changes. If the original data is not $iid$ normal, other assumptions are needed, and the results are asymptotic.

Comment: On the contrary, the distribution of $t$ is *different* for every $n$ because the degrees of freedom matter!